# ffmpeg: Select frames at % position of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a 2x2 tile thumbnail of a video, that contains frames from 20%, 40%, 60%, and 80% through a video. I see that I need to use a video filter, with select, but can't work out what options will do this. I want to do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(pos\,0.2)),tile=2x2" tile.png
```

Where position would be the position in the video from 0.0 to 1.0. How do I do this, or what are my options?

Comment: Offtopic. What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard programming: n. the process of writing computer programs. I'm writing a computer program. Thanks for ruining SO. https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d

Comment: Seems like a `ffmpeg` cli usage question to me. See [tag:ffmpeg] tag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- **Method 1: Frame intervals**

  This may take some time depending on the input or return `N/A` for certain types of inputs (see the duration based method in this case).

  Get the total number of `video` frames:

  ```
  ffprobe <input> -select_streams v -show_entries stream=nb_frames -of default=nk=1:nw=1 -v quiet
  ```

  The command will output an integer value, for example:

  ```
  18034
  ```

  For the example above the frame interval is `nb_frames / 5 = 18034 / 5 = 3607`

  Finally the `ffmpeg` command is:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i <input> -filter:v "select=(gte(n\,3607))*not(mod(n\,3607)),tile=2x2" -frames:v 1 -vsync vfr -y tile.png
  ```
- **Method 2: Duration intervals**

  Same idea as above but use a duration in seconds. This can also take a while and the reported duration may be invalid (eg: if the file is truncated).

  ```
  ffprobe <input> -select_streams v -show_entries stream=duration -of default=nk=1:nw=1 -v quiet
  ```

  It returns a real value like:

  ```
  601.133333
  ```

  Your interval is `601 / 5 ~= 120` seconds:

  ```
  ffmpeg -i <input> -filter:v "select=(gte(t\,120))*(isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,120)),tile=2x2" -frames:v 1 -y tile.png
  ```
- **Method 3: Seek & extract**

  Seek to a specific time with `-ss -i`, extract a single frame and use imagemagick's `montage` to create the tile.

  Example output for a 10 minute countdown timer:

  [image]

Comment: There's no way to do this without reading through the entire file? The way `-ss` before `-i` does?

Comment: You could find the total duration with `ffprobe`, seek at a specific time and extract one frame with four separate `ffmpeg` commands and join the resulting images with imagemagick (`montage`?).

Comment: I think I might have to go that route. Thanks very much.

Comment: Note that duration as stated by the file can be somewhat fragile. It may be incorrect or even missing. Workaround is to completely decode the file, as this answer does.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I just realized that counting the frames might fail for certain inputs (eg: MPEG-TS Annex B). In fact, and maybe you can confirm, I think `ffprobe` takes just the header information if present or estimates duration based on rate and it doesn't parse the whole input file? I'll have to check the sources later.