# ffmpeg: Create cap (video screenshot) at given frame more performant

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to find a solution that creates caps (video screenshots) at given framerates and is more performant than my current way:

```
ffmpeg -i "/path/to/video.mp4" -vf "select=gte(n\,10000)" -vframes 1 "/path/to/cap.png"
```

I have a zillion videos, each between 10 minutes and 2 hours and I need exactly 6 caps per video. With my current way it takes ages, as ffmpeg is "walking" though the video to find the next frame where it should take the cap. This "walking time" makes almost 99% of job which is currently about 4 minutes per video (depending on its length).

I'm wondering if there's maybe a way of telling ffmpeg to "jump" right to the given frame. It doesn't even need to be exact this frame. If theres  a keyframe around to make it faster that's fine.

Anything that can point me in the right direction is very much appreciated!

Comment: See my answer here, third option, and the comments: [ffmpeg: Select frames at % position of video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043680/ffmpeg-select-frames-at-position-of-video). You will have to use the video duration which may be inaccurate or missing but if you have it you can seek to specific  positions and extract a single frame.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using -ss -i in another script already but it's also "scanning" the whole videofile and not "jumping" to the given position within the video. Am I doing something wrong? Is you methode realy jumping to the position or also scanning the file until the position is reached?

Comment: `-ss -i` parses the input,  `-i -ss` decodes. The first method is faster.