# Android FFmpeg ComplexCommand to remove frames from the back of a video

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

Compiled using

> compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

Currently i have only managed to come up with a complexcommand that removes duplicate frames, and only start to capture frames from frame 25 onwards of a video like so:

`String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-framerate", "60", "-vf", "select='gte(n,25)'", "-vsync", "0",  dest.getAbsolutePath()};`

`select='gte(n,25)'` will return me all frames from frame 25 onwards.

`"-vsync", "0"` will remove duplicate frames.

**Now i want to ALSO remove certain number of frames from the back of the video, for e.g. i want to remove the last 20 frames. How do I go about doing that?**

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435639/6950238) answer

Comment: FFmpeg for android doesnt have ffprobe